# How to add a class to body only a route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a class called: `product-page-bottom-padding`

now I want to add this class only `/product/{slug}` route to `body` element. It must removing in other routes.

How to handle this scenario?

Comment: The best approach in my opinion would be to send the class name as props to the component when calling route. Then the component can have a condition like `className={classProp? classProp : null)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the class to the body in the useEffect hook of component which you are rendering for `/product/{slug}` something like:

```
function ChildComponent() {
   useEffect(() => {
      document.body.classList.add("product-page-bottom-padding");
      
      return () => {
         document.body.classList.remove("product-page-bottom-padding");
      }
   }, [])
// other body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Next.js, ***every page(Route)*** is considered as a ***separate component*** so you can wrap it with ***Conditional (ternary) operator*** as following :

```
className={condition? firstClass: secondClass}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement following method on your route `/product/{slug}` component

```js
export default YourComponent = ( props ) => {

  const { unique_id } = props // incase your want dynamic class

   useEffect( ()=> {
     // Added class when route active
     document.body.classList.add(`MyClass ${unique_id}`); 
   
     return function cleanup() {
      // Remove class when route changed
      document.body.classList.remove(`MyClass ${unique_id}`);
     };

   })
  // other code
}
```